# VScode Python "Run Cell" does nothing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I'm using VScode on mac and configured an anaconda environment. When I insert `# %%` and hit "Run Cell", nothing happens at all.

How can I fix this?

EDIT: the solution was simply to reboot my machine :)

Comment: Please provide enough information. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Or try to reinstall vscode and python extension directly.

Comment: make sure you have installed jupyter and notebook in your conda environment

Comment: How do I do that @nnzzll

Comment: @jimbob97 activate your env in terminal and run `pip install jupyter notebook`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I insert and hit "Run Cell", nothing happens at all

If you can create `.ipynb` file which can be successfully run, there should be no problem.

Try reload window and give the interactive window more time to load:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The window didn't appear for me either